# How to programmatically turn off/on monitor on Raspberry Pi2 with Windows 10 IoT Core

Tags: raspberry-pi2, windows-10-iot-core

How to programmatically turn off/on monitor connected to Raspberry Pi 2 via the HDMI cable. The Raspberry Pi is used operating system Windows 10 IoT Core (10586).
I try user32.dll and SendMessage, but it does not work.
"Unable to load DLL 'user32.dll'. The specified module could not be found."

Comment: The user32.dll is part of x86 Windows, and as such doesn't exist on the ARM based Win IoT. There *might* be an equivalent. You can check for one here: https://ms-iot.github.io/content/en-US/win10/tools/IoTAPIPortingTool.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can't send messages on current version of Windows IoT Core. There's actually no way to programmatically change power management options or interact with a monitor.

Comment: Could you check the answer or update your question accordingly ?